# Ошибка module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'

Tags: python, datetime

Вот код, в котором две переменные `datetime.date` я пытаюсь соединить со временем `00:00` и `23:30` соответственно в один объект `datetime.datetime`
Код:

```
import datetime

fstart = datetime.date(2012, 6, 20)
fend = datetime.date(2012, 8, 23)

start = datetime.combine(fstart, datetime.time(0,0))
end = datetime.combine(fend, datetime.time(23, 30))
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    start = datetime.combine(fstart, datetime.time(0,0))
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'
```

Comment: from datetime import datetime, date, combine

Comment: Короче говоря, combine находится внутри еще одного datetime. Т.е. писать надо datetime.datetime.combine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
start = datetime.datetime.combine(fstart, datetime.time(0,0))
end = datetime.datetime.combine(fend, datetime.time(23, 30))
```

Первый datetime это модуль, второй datetime - это класс в модуля datetime, а combine это метод класса. Если не путаю.
Все время думаю, зачем они эту путаницу сделали.